# Print using a button from window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following button which opens a new window

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-lg green" onclick="PrintElem('#sample_editable_1', 'Fault Recording')"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right: 5px;"></i>Run Report</a>
```

In my js file, I have this function which creates the window:-

```
function PrintElem(elem, h1)
{
      Popup($(elem).html(), h1);
}

function Popup(data, h1) 
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=768,width=1024');
    mywindow.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">');
    mywindow.document.write('<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+base_url+'/css/print1.css'+'" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+base_url+'/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'+'" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('<script src="'+base_url+'js/custom.js'+'" type="text/javascript"></script>');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
    mywindow.document.write('<h1 class="pdfTitleDv" >'+h1+'</h1>');
    mywindow.document.write($('#window_print').html());
    mywindow.document.write('<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed flip-content table-hover datatableDv " id="sample_editable_1">');
    mywindow.document.write(data);
    mywindow.document.write('</table>');
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    mywindow.document.close();
    mywindow.focus();
    return true;
}

function print(){
    window.print();
}
```

I have the following button in the new window which I created there I have a button I want to print the table which is in the window. please see the HTML below:-

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right btm-btn">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-lg green" onclick="print()"><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right: 5px;"></i>Print</a> 
</div>
```

I want to print the table which is in the new window. Can anyone help me to achieve this?? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add `window.print()` in your print function, It will push it to print forcefully.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add: `mywindow.print()`. Because window refers to the current window, you need to print the new window. So, make `mywindow` variable global and call print method.

```
var mywindow;
function Popup(data, h1) 
{
    mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=768,width=1024');
   //rest of your code
} 
function print(){
    mywindow.print();
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hLfvr3uy/)

Comment: Can you give me an example??

Comment: I don't think the js is working because I did alert it did not prompt anything.

Comment: @AlekStephanok It is working perfectly in my case! Added a demo in the answer. Please show what's not working.

Comment: the print button is in the new window that is opening in the popup.....that's the requirement. Is this possible??

Comment: Actually browser is blocking the popup. You can try in the local environment.

Comment: You can add script as well!

Comment: It's the same as adding HTML just wrap JS into script tags!

Answer (score 0):

try to use "innerHTML" rather than "document.write" with `` back-ticks like this example :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">click here to open the new window</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   mywindow = window.open('', '', 'height=768,width=1024');

  mywindow.document.body.innerHTML = `<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>`;

  mywindow.window.print();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```